# How to get SMTP-ID in sendgrid API through json?

Tags: java, json, web-services, email, sendgrid

How to get SMTP-ID in sendgrid API through json? Example :
In the API tutorial they have mentioned to execute
http(s)://username:password@domain/foo.php

and the result will be  (in json):
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337197600,
    "smtp-id": "<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
    "event": "processed"
But actually we need the perfect url to get json.
for eg : 
https://sendgrid.com/api/bounces.get.json
for bounce mails
similarly , is there anything to get the above sample json.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you send an Email to SendGrid through the Web API, you won't have an SMTP-ID. That will be generated by the SendGrid server that translates the API call to an SMTP object. So you're right, the SMTP-ID that comes back in the Event POST isn't helpful.

However, you can add [Unique Args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html) to your API call using the [x-smtpapi argument in the mail.send call](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send). This will let you define whatever tracking metric(s) you want to the message, and it will all come back on the Event POST.

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use Unique Args feature, please do remember that they will appear in the **most** Event notifications but not **all of them**. Please refer for the details to the sendgrid forum topics which include "missing unique_args" and similar. So, think twice before "building the entire infrastructure" around this feature like some of us did :(

Comment: The only events that might be missing unique_args is the rare returned-undeliverable Bounce event, when the returning server has stripped the relevant headers so Sendgrid can't associate the returned message to the original sent.

Answer (score 2):

I got my answer .
Actually we can try event API using a callback url, that receives POST request having every details about the email delivered, bounced in json format. Whenever some event is triggered we get a request from Sendgrid. Thats cool.

We can keep these details for further Filtering.

Anyway , thanks jacobmovingfwd